# How to display long text to multiple line in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Here is the xml:

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/headword_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

The ListView is showed using the following code:

```
headwordList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.headword_list);

        adapter = new MdxAdapter(getSherlockActivity());
        adapter.setDict(dict, getString(R.string.empty_entry_list),
                getString(R.string.invalid_dict));
        headwordList.setAdapter(adapter);

        rootView.requestFocus();
```

The problem I faced is when the text that I would like to display in the list is too long to be fitted to the width, the remaining text is automatically truncated to ...
What I should do so that I can display the long text to 2 or more line, so that the complete text can be seen?

Comment: Post your list item view XML layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after I found the entry list item view and made the following change:

```
<TextView android:text="TextView01" android:textSize="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingLeft="10dp"
              android:paddingRight="10dp"
              android:id="@+id/entry_headword"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView layout is irrelevant here, you'll have to use a custom View for your Adapter.

Here's an example: http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/twitter/5/listview-custom-adapter-example

Answer (score 0):

In the xml of the getView of your adapter set the following properties to TextView.

maxlines="no_of_lines_of_ur_choice";

lines="no_of_lines_of_ur_choice";

This may help.